# Apply a list of functions to a value

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, lisp

I'm looking for something that is probably very well defined in Clojure (in the Lisp world at large in fact) but I don't have enough experience or culture to get on the right track and Google hasn't been very helpful so far.

Let's say I have three simple forms:

```
(defn add-one   [v] (+ v 1))
(defn add-two   [v] (+ v 2))
(defn add-three [v] (+ v 3))
```

Out of convenience, they are stored in a vector. In the real world, that vector would vary depending on the context:

```
(def operations
  [add-one
   add-two
   add-three])
```

And I also have an initial value:

```
(def value 42)
```

Now, I would like to apply all the functions in that vector to that value and get the result of the combined operations:

```
(loop [ops operations
       val value]
  (if (empty? ops)
    val
    (recur (rest ops)
           ((first ops) val))))
```

While this does work, I'm surprised there isn't a higher level form just for that. I've looked all over the place but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The functional phrase you are searching for is `(apply comp operations)`:

```
((apply comp operations) 42)
;48
```

---

Your loop *does* work if you feed it `42` for `value`:

```
(loop [ops operations
       val 42]
  (if (empty? ops)
    val
    (recur (rest ops)
           ((first ops) val))))
;48
```

This applies the operations in the opposite order from [`comp`](http://conj.io/1.6.0/clojure.core/comp/).

... As does using `reduce`:

```
(reduce (fn [v f] (f v)) 42 operations)
;48
```

If you look at the source code for `comp`, you'll find that the general case essentially  executes a `loop` similar to yours upon a `reverse`d list of the supplied functions.

Comment: Interesting. I found out about `comp` but was under the impression that it was not taking me closer to a working solution.

Comment: @Bourdon As you see, `comp` is not too hard to implement, but `apply` is fundamental.

Answer (score 1):

'In Lisp world at large' you can use `reduce`:

```
user> (reduce (fn [x y] (y x)) 5 [inc inc inc inc])
;; => 9
```

This may look not so sexy, but it works everywhere with minor variations (this is Common Lisp, for example):

```
CL-USER> (reduce (lambda (x y) (funcall y x))
                 '(1+ 1+ 1+ 1+)
                 :initial-value 5)
9
```